# Spaces where compact sets are closed under countable union

Tags: general-topology

Are there non-compact spaces such that a countable union of compact subspaces is always compact?

If so, are there any non-compact spaces (necessarily uncountable) such that a subset is countable iff it is compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, every non-compact spact has a non-compact countable subspace. (Of course a countable space is a countable union of compact sets.)

Suppose $X$ is not compact, and let $\mathcal V$ be an open cover of $X$ having no finite subcover. Choose a sequence $x_0,V_0,x_1,V_1,\dots,x_n,V_n,\dots$ as follows. Having chosen $x_1,V_1,\dots,x_{n-1},V_{n-1}$, choose $x_n\in X\setminus(V_0\cup\cdots\cup V_{n-1})$ (possible since $\{V_0,\dots,V_{n-1}\}$ is not a cover of $X$) and then choose $V_n\in\mathcal V$ so that $x_n\in V_n$ (possible since $\mathcal V$ is a cover of $X$).

Now $\{x_0,x_1,\dots\}$ is a countable subspace of $X$ which is not compact, because $\{V_0,V_1,\dots\}$ is an open cover with no finite subcover. Since $\{x_0,x_1,\dots\}$ is a countable union of compact sets, this answers the **first question** in the negative.

**Second question:** Is there any space $X$ in which a subset is compact iff it is countable?

Such a space is necessarily **countable**: if $X$ is uncountable, either $X$ is compact (so it's an uncountable compact subset of itself), or else $X$ is non-compact, and then it has a countable non-compact subset, as shown above.

On the other hand, there are countable spaces in which every subset is compact. Any finite space has this property; more generally, any space in which every nonempty open set is cofinite; or any finite topological sum of such spaces.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This works with minor adjustments.

Comment: Also shows first question's answer is no :)

Comment: There is no need to "assume" that $V_n$ is not a subset of $V_0\cup\cdots V_{n-1}$, that follows from $x_n\notin V_0\cup\cdots\cup V_{n-1}$ and $x_n\in V_n$.

Comment: My answer was addressed specifically to your second question. As for your second question, there are **countable** spaces in which every subspace is compact.

Comment: you're right i misread, but it answers the first question too right? because points are compact, so then every countable is compact so space is compact. also yeah I should slightly correct the question, as it stands it's a bit misleading

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Are there non-compact spaces such that a countable union of compact subspaces is always compact?" I don't have a proof, but it seems unlikely. In any case, it doesn't seem "natural" to ask about the union being compact, seems more sensible to ask about the closure of the union.

Let $X=\omega_1$, the set of countable ordinals with the order topology. Then $S\subset X$ is countable if and only if $\overline S$ is compact, answering a revised version of the second question. Also any compact subset is countable and hence the closure of a countable union of compact subsets is  compact.

Comment: Interesting, thanks very much for this contribution. I agree that your amendment seems more natural, especially if one likes Hausdorff spaces. Still curious about my original question though, but this gives me more ideas.

Comment: also I'm surprised your intuition says no for even the first question, I'll try to think about a possible proof then since I was thinking about constructions before.

Comment: @davik A yes to the first question would imply that every countable set is compact. I (evidently) can't imagine how that could be.

Comment: If you have trivial topology, then every set is compact, but how to add more open sets to make uncountable sets noncompact is not obvious to me